# Using mozilla cacert.pem file, error: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: curl, openssl, libcurl

I have a program using libcurl but I am getting an error:

```
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: c:\MinGW_New\ssl\misc\demoCA\cacert.pem
  CApath: none
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection #0`enter code here`
```

I tried to append the mozilla certificates from the http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem file but I still get the same error.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

I set the CAINFO option in curl to the correct path to my mozilla certificate. That part is verified working.

Do I need to sign my mozilla pem file? Im using openssl, how do you do this?